# how to improve this php array data retrieval?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Wondering whether any improvement can be done to speed up this array?

test array row count is 40,000 record.

it took very long time for the loop to be completed.

sample value:

```
$test[] = array(
    'products_id' => $data['products_id'],
    'products_extra_fields_id' => $data['products_extra_fields_id'],
    'products_extra_fields_name' => $data['products_extra_fields_name'],
    'products_extra_fields_value' => $data['products_extra_fields_value']
    );



foreach productid
{

  $colname="column name";


    //this inside for loop making thing very slow
    foreach ($test as $key1 => $row1)
    {
        $w= $row1['products_id'];
        $x= $row1['products_extra_fields_id'];
        $y= $row1['products_extra_fields_name'];
        $z= $row1['products_extra_fields_value'];

        if( ($w==$products_id) && ($y== $colname) )
        {
            $wantedvalue=$z;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have a chance of having duplicate $data['products_id']

Comment: have you thought about using a database for that?

Comment: I am reading it from db, and want properly format it before export into excel. Directly query db might slower (resource intensive)

Comment: yes, less than 5 duplicate records.

Comment: i have addd a answer, please check, that will work

Comment: @ineedhelp The `$wantedvalue=$z` part makes me think you're searching for something; am I right about that?

Comment: yes, the dictionary/hashtable concept to directly retrieve data solved my problem. It cut down the whole process from 1 hour to 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can build the array $test[] as dictionary (user products_id . "_" . products_extra_fields_name as key)

   $test[$data['products_id'] ."_".$data['products_extra_fields_name']] = array(
           'products_id' => $data['products_id'],
           'products_extra_fields_id' => $data['products_extra_fields_id'],
           'products_extra_fields_name' => $data['products_extra_fields_name'],
           'products_extra_fields_value' => $data['products_extra_fields_value']
   );

Once you do this, you can directly index the array since you already have column name and products_id

Comment: when I retrieve data, $search= $products_id."_".$colname;    $test[$search]['products_extra_fields_value'], php warn me on Notice: Undefined index:

Comment: try, only $test[$search] and if you still get the undefined index, then all values might not have got loaded, otherwise use var_dump to analyze the data and check child array has the proper structure

Comment: still undefined, I check the var dump, looks ok.     array(4) { ["products_id"]=> string(4) "1343" ["products_extra_fields_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["products_extra_fields_name"]=> string(7) "Product" ["products_extra_fields_value"]=> string(52) "Fluorite strand" } 
Notice: Undefined index: 1343_Author

Comment: then problem lies in $test[$search], can you paste the var_dump of $test

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is the array you need to edit. If you are retrieving these data from a database then you have to speed up your sql query. Additionally you can add indexes to your feilds.
this is a link you can refer to.
http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-sql-tips-to-speed-up-your-database